# How to trigger tooltip using iMacros

Tags: imacros

I want to capture the screenshots of tooltip which appears when I mouseover the image. The image contains title attribute. The code mentioned below is higlighting the image with a border but its not showing the tooltip.
`TAG POS=3 TYPE=IMG ATTR=HREF:http://* CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the EVENT commant instead of TAG in this case, e.g.:

```
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEDOWN XPATH=".//body/descendant::img[3]" BUTTON=0
```

more info: [Imacros wiki > EVENT](http://wiki.imacros.net/EVENT)